# htop shows different number of processes for Chromium browser on Linux vs FreeBSD

Tags: chrome, htop

`htop` output on a **Linux** machine shows lots of processes for Chromium browser while it only shows few processes for Chromium on **FreeBSD**.

Why is there any difference?

#### Linux:

[image]

#### FreeBSD:

[image]

Also, my observation is that Chromium browser on Linux has a very high CPU usage specially when watching YouTube videos, but on FreeBSD, the CPU usage is much lower.

---

Filtering `htop` output for only Chromium with `\chrom`, showing as tree with `t`, and showing all threads with `H`, the htop output is like this:

#### Linux:

[image]

#### FreeBSD:

[image]

Comment: To ease the reading I suggest the following: 1/Filter the chrom{e,ium} process by typing `\chrom` 2/Display a tree of processes with `t` 3/Make sure you do (or don't) display user process threads with `H` (capital h).

Comment: @abitmol I implemented you suggestion

Comment: “htop output on a Linux machine shows lots of processes for Chromium browser while it only shows few processes for Chromium” is something missing at the end of this sentence, like “on FreeBSD”? Do make sure you aren't mixing up *processes* and *threads* (htop can be configured to show each kernel thread separately or not). And IIRC the answer is yes, Chromium puts more tabs per processes on FreeBSD.